# A code that looks for a file name in a specific directory and store in in the array list

Tags: java, arraylist

Good morning everyone,

I'm stuck here with a code that I'm trying to make work. The goal of this code is to make a recursive algorithm to find all files that matched a target file name. Each string should store the pathname to the matching file. Return null if no matching files are found. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListFiles 
{
    public static ArrayList searchForFile
    (File dir, ArrayList filePaths, String target)
    {
        if (!dir.isDirectory())
            return null;
        else 
        {
            File[] files=dir.listFiles();
            for (int index = 0; index < filePaths; index++)
            {
                if(files[index].isFile())
                {
                    if(files[index].getName().equals(target))
                    {
                        filePaths.add(files[index].toString());
                    }
                }
            else if(files[index].isDirectory())
                searchForFile(files[index], filePaths, target);
            }
        }
    return filePaths;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList filePaths = new ArrayList();
        File rootFolder = new File("F:\\java");
        String targetFile = "sample.txt";
        filePaths = searchForFile(rootFolder, filePaths, targetFile);
        if(filePaths==null)
            System.out.println("No file is found");
        else
        {
            for (String string : filePaths)
            {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am very new to programming and apologize in advance if I'm missing something very obvious. Thank you in advance and have a great day!

Comment: What is your problem with this code ?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and I have two errors, in line for '(int index = 0; index < filePaths; index++)' and ' for (String string : filePaths)', Sorry I'm trying to understand how to make it look like code in the comments, but can't so far.

Comment: You should append the error messages to your post.

Comment: macmoonshine, I apologize and thank you for an advice, the only error message I have right now is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String" for "for (String string : filePaths)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this error `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String" for "for (String string : filePaths).` " change your code to this :

```
ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        File rootFolder = new File("F:\\java");
        String targetFile = "sample.txt";
        filePaths = searchForFile(rootFolder, filePaths, targetFile);
        if(filePaths==null)
            System.out.println("No file is found");
        else
        {
            for (String string : filePaths)
            {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
```

FilePaths is an arraylist and it should be as follows :

```
 for (int index = 0; index < files.length; index++)
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem, appreciate your time.

Comment: Glad to help you .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your problem:

```
int index = 0; index < filePaths; index++
```

FilePaths is an arraylist and you're using it as integer.
You probably wanted to iterate through files? Try

```
int index = 0; index < files.length; index++
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it, for a first part. But I'm still getting "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String" for "for (String string : filePaths)".